# Django save() method not inserting data to database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am facing a strange problem while inserting data to database using Django `models.save()` method. I have been using save() method in some other apps of same project. In this app named payments, I am getting `post`request from a payment gateway and I am inserting data into database on success

Structure of my payment model is given below:

**Payment Model**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class payments(models.Model):
    transactionId = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=None)
    uniqueOrderId = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=None)
    userId = models.CharField(max_length=30,default=None)
    productId = models.CharField(max_length=30,default=None)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=30,default=None)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=30,default=None)
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context, Template,RequestContext
import datetime
import hashlib
from random import randint
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect, csrf_exempt
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from questions.models import questions as questionData
from payments.models import payments

def success(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    status=request.POST["status"]
    firstname=request.POST["firstname"]
    amount=request.POST["amount"]
    txnid=request.POST["txnid"]
    posted_hash=request.POST["hash"]
    key=request.POST["key"]
    productinfo=request.POST["productinfo"]
    email=request.POST["email"]
    uniqueOrder = request.POST["paymentGatewayOrderID"]
    useridReturn = request.POST["udf1"]
    productIdReturn = request.POST["udf2"]
    salt="mysecretsalt"
    try:
        additionalCharges=request.POST["additionalCharges"]
        retHashSeq=additionalCharges+'|'+salt+'|'+status+'|||||||||||'+email+'|'+firstname+'|'+productinfo+'|'+amount+'|'+txnid+'|'+key
    except Exception:
        retHashSeq = salt+'|'+status+'|||||||||||'+email+'|'+firstname+'|'+productinfo+'|'+amount+'|'+txnid+'|'+key
    hashh=hashlib.sha512(retHashSeq).hexdigest().lower()
    if(hashh !=posted_hash):
        print "Invalid Transaction. Please try again"
    else:
        paymentDataInsert = payments(transactionId=txnid,userId=useridReturn,productId=productIdReturn,amount=amount,uniqueOrderId=uniqueOrder,date="today")
        paymentDataInsert.save()
        print "Thank You. Your order status is ", status
        print "Your Transaction ID for this transaction is ",txnid
        print "We have received a payment of Rs. ", amount ,". Your order will soon be shipped."
        return render_to_response('success.html',RequestContext(request,{"txnid":txnid,"status":status,"amount":amount,"useridReturn":useridReturn,"uniqueOrder":uniqueOrder,"productIdReturn":productIdReturn}))
```

Payment is processing correctly and all the data correctly rendered on the success.html template.

But data is not inserted into table even though I correctly called

```
paymentDataInsert = payments(transactionId=txnid,userId=useridReturn,productId=productIdReturn,amount=amount,uniqueOrderId=uniqueOrder,date="today")
paymentDataInsert.save()
```

Strange thing is, it is not showing any error message. I tried my best to solve the problem, but no success.

**Edit 1**

I tried `paymentDataInsert.save()` from another function in a different view with a default value for the entries. Then it worked. It seems like the problem is only for that specific function.

Comment: try using payment.objects.create()
no need to call the save method

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib so, should I use paymentDataInsert.create()

Comment: no need to store into the variable paymentDataInsert.

replace the two lines with payment.objects.create(pass values here)

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib Tried, But still no success :(

Comment: which django and python version are you using ? and are there any errors on the console if there is can you please paste the traceback